# Which http statuscodes to use for external APIs in a REST service?

Tags: web-services, rest, http-status-codes

I have a REST webservice that encapsulates multiple external APIs.
Let's assume my customers can input a `BookingId` to my `REST` webservice. I then pass that id to the external api and return the booking, if possible.

Now, if the bookingid does not exist, the external API response with `HTTP 200` and some custom message.

But I'd like to show the correct HTTP statuscode to my clients.

Question: which code would you expect a webservice to return incase you enter eg an invalid/nonexisting bookingid?

Probably one of the `4xx` client error codes? As the invalid bookingid was given by the client.

But which one?
`400 Bad Request` if for invalid query parameters (not values).
`404 Not Found` is for (static?) resources not available anymore.

Comment: Independent if your service is a facade or something like that. A similar question can be found [What's the most appropriate HTTP status code for an “item not found” error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604816/whats-the-most-appropriate-http-status-code-for-an-item-not-found-error-page) . The answer is: Stick with `404`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick overview of the most used HTTP codes

```
403 : Not Acceptable (useful when for example a parameter is missing)
404 : Not Found
500 : Server Error
200 : OK
201 : Inserted (use it when you put somthing)
418 : I'm a teapot
```

You can also use some custom codes e.g :

`10003 two entries cannot have the same id`