# What's an appropriate HTTP status code for "requested resource isn't found"?

Tags: rest, http

What HTTP status code is better to use in the following case?

I have a REST API to get some database entity basing on its id. The case is when the requested entity cannot be found in the database.

Comment: 404 Not Found...?

Comment: I would refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5604832/1519409).

Comment: @inavda, thanks! that was useful to read

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the most appropriate HTTP status code for an "item not found" error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604816/whats-the-most-appropriate-http-status-code-for-an-item-not-found-error-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`404` is the status code suitable for this situation. It indicates a *client error* and indicates that a representation cannot be found for requested resource.

From the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), the document that defines the semantics of the HTTP/1.1 protocol:

> [**6.5.4.  404 Not Found**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)
>
> The `404` (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. A `404` status code does not indicate whether this lack of representation is temporary or permanent; the `410`(Gone) status code is preferred over `404` if the origin server knows, presumably through some configurable means, that the condition is likely to be permanent.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use 404.
That being said here's a wikipedia link for HTTP status codes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @sys463 Your API *resource* is the db entity.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799198/what-are-rest-resources